# How can I place taskkill.exe into my System32 folder?

Tags: cmd, windows-xp, windows-10, taskkill

I just got a Windows XP computer, and I was wondering if its possible to copy the Taskkill command from my windows 10 computer to the other computer so that I can use it? When I tried just copy and pasting it said "taskkill is not a valid win executable".  Thanks for any help! !

-EDG

Comment: `taskkill` is available by default for Windows XP __Professional__ according to Microsoft's [Taskkill](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx) documentation for Windows XP and SS64 article about [taskkill](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html). I suggest to get `taskkill.exe` from a Windows XP Professional installation for your Windows XP __Home__ instead of copying it from Windows 10 to avoid compatibility problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a version that you can download from the internet including instrutions:
http://greasypc.blogspot.co.at/2008/02/want-to-use-taskkill-but-you-have-xp.html

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 are 64bits, and sounds like a 32bit XP is in question. It won't work.

Comment: That is no good answer. All 64-bit Windows have 2 `System32` folders: `%SystemRoot%\System32` with 64-bit EXEs and DLLs for 64-bit applications and `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` with 32-bit EXEs and DLLs for 32-bit applications. `taskkill.exe` exists therefore as 32-bit and as 64-bit console application on 64-bit Windows and 32-bit version could be copied. But I suppose (not able to test it) that even 32-bit `taskkill` of `Windows 10` won't run on Windows XP because of Windows kernel incompatibility.